# How to change the default highlighting of gedit for a specific extension

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

Everytime I open a .m file, gedit associates Octave highlighting to it.
I would like to change the default behavior to Matlab.

How can I, in general, change the default highlighting that gedit gives to a file associated to one extension to another language?

Answer (score 5):

You could change /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs files but instead copy this file to your home or you will lose changes on upgrade.
`$ cp /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/octave.lang ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/`
change
`<property name="globs">*.m</property>`
to
`<property name="globs"></property>`

I also did some experimenting and found out objc.lang file also has the same line so you maybe need to copy and change that too.

Comment: Is there a more nicely way of doing it. Like configure the precedence of the languages, instead of disabling octave?

Comment: What do I do after copying to $HOME dir? How do I tell gedit that it needs to look at the new file xyz.lang in $HOME??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that in modern versions of gedit (e.g. gedit 3.34.0 on Ubuntu 19.10) the correct directory is ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-4 .